# json get object without knowing it's name

Tags: javascript, json

I have some json being returned from a jquery ajax function.

Here is an example of said json:

```
        var b =
        {
            "SelectByUserResult": [{ "DateAdded": "/Date(1357300130930+0000)/", "Deleted": false, "FileExtension": "jpg", "Filename": "e5d1ee90-f3c0-4dd7-9996-d1725a1fc031.jpg", "Height": 768, "Id": 955, "IsBpMember": true, "OriginalFilename": "Tulips.jpg", "SessionId": "277d31bf-84e1-4678-ad66-e7b332936219", "Title": "New image", "TotalRecords": 16, "UserId": "ded98560-61d0-42f2-944e-30280d54e94b", "Width": 1024}]
        }
```

I have other ajax functions which return similar json in a similar structure, the only difference is the object 'SelectByUserResult' might be changed to 'SelectByIdResult' or 'SelectByNameResult'.

So in my ajax function (in the success function) I would do this to access the json b.SelectByUserResult

I want to be able to access that object but without specifying the name (as it's not always known). How would I go about doing that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My funny variant (maybe not the best). It will return the first property of the object, I guess this is what you need.

```
function getFirstProp(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) return obj[i];
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log(getFirstProp(b));
```